# Strange Black Square at the Top-Left Side of the Screen in Xubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, whisker

A strange black square appears at the top-left side of the screen. I log in, it does not appear until I open Whisker menu, but whenever I open it, it simply appears and stays at the top of all application windows.

It is not a functional problem but it is getting annoying. This is the screenshot while Whisker menu is open:

[image]

It might sometimes imitate the wallpaper, ss:

[image]

Comment: Could it be a tool tip of some sort?

Comment: It does not seem so, will not fade out while I'm busy with other applications. It stays black, but can change color in time like this: http://i.hizliresim.com/EqAv0v.png . This is actually color of the wallpaper, I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Are you using Thunar as your file manager?

Comment: Yes. I use Thunar.

Comment: this happened to me on Ubuntu 19.10, Zac's solution fixed the problem

Comment: I do not use Ubuntu now @Pafnucy (now I use Manjaro KDE). Remi's solution worked for me in the past and I think it's easier to script it (because it does not deal with window id which changes on each rebot), it can be launched it on login. Since both works, I'm not quite sure which one to accept after years later. You say you solved your problem but if any googler has this problem, can they try out [this script](https://pastie.io/vonkjf.bash)? If this solves anyone's problem, I can accept Remi's as accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Xubuntu 12.04.5 user here, I launched `xwininfo` command from a shell, and point to the black rectangle, it says:

> xwininfo: Window id: 0x240007d (has no name)

launching command `xkill -id 0x240007d` did close the black rectange.

The window id is not the same every time: this time wininfo shows an id of 0x360007b.

Moreover, I played an openGL game and the rectangle is no more black, but shows a bit of game graphics.

Comment: Does window id change on each reboot?

Comment: This worked for me in Linux Mint 20 with MATE desktop. Clipit seems not to play well with MATE...?

Answer (score 2):

Try in a terminal

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -t bool -s false
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -t bool -s true
```

The square disappears, but you need to do after each reboot of the computer.

I found this solution on another forum. I don't understand why that works.

Comment: Thanks... ^^ However, I found another permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's another permanent solution to this issue.

If you install another Ubuntu with desktop environment (like Kubuntu) and then install Xubuntu and completely uninstall the old environment, the black square will not appear.